# In Sharepoint 2013, how do I hide the content of a List?

Tags: list, sharepoint

I want to restrict users from seeing the content of a list when they navigate to "site/Lists//AllItems.aspx". All I want them to see is the message "There are no items to show in this view of the "" list." I've already checked permissions but everything is set properly. We are not using audience targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the list view to use a filter that returns no result. For example, if the smallest ID in the list is 9, set the filter to show `ID equals 8`

Such hacks will not prevent savvy users from viewing the data though. Access and permissions should be configured properly. Consider removing user access to that list entirely, so only administrators can see it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will certainly try that to see if it satisfies our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First break permission on your list or library by "Stop Inheriting Permissions"

1. Go to the list, library, or survey and open it.
2. Go to the Permissions page using the steps in the previous section.
3. To break permissions inheritance from the parent, select Stop Inheriting Permissions.

Assign unique permissions in SharePoint 2019, 2016, or 2013 server
You must break inheritance from the parent site before you can grant unique permissions. Once you've broken inheritance using the steps in the section above, follow these steps to grant unique permissions:

1. Go to the list, library, or survey and open it.
2. Go to the Permissions page using the steps in the previous section.
3. Select Grant Permissions on the Permissions tab.

Delete Unique Permissions button
Note: If the list or library is inheriting from the parent, you won't see Grant Permissions.

In the Share... dialog box, make sure Invite people is selected, and then type the names of the people or group you want to grant access to in the Enter names or email addresses... box.

Share dialog box

Add a personal message if you like.

Check or uncheck Share everything in this folder, even items with unique permissions. This will grant or restrict access to items you already set unique permissions for. (This option is only available for folders.)

The permission level granted is set to Edit by default, which means the people you invite can make some changes to the list, library, or survey. If you want to grant a different permission level like Read only, click Show options and change the selection in the Select a permission level box.

An email message will be sent to everyone in the Invite people box. If you don't want this to happen, click Show options, and uncheck Send an email invitation.

When you're done, click Share.

Hope this can solve your issue:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782